# javascript - Fetch API until there is no data

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am using a restful API, and I need to post some data.
but before, I need to ensure that the table is empty. The problem I am facing is that the delete method of this API return success, but does not immediately delete the data, this data is sent to a queue to delete asap.

So before I call the post method, I need to check if I have any items on this table. How can I call this method several times to ensure that the post method will only be executed when the table is empty?

```
async function run() {

    apiDelete()
    .then(() => console.log('deleting')) 
    .then(() => {

        getItems().
        then(() => {
            
            apiPost()
             .then(() => console.log('posting...'))
             .catch(e => console.log(e))
        })
       
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))     
     
  return

}
```

The methods:

```
async function apiPost() {
  const url = 'https://apipost.com/data/v2/1234'
  const options = {
    method: 'POST'
  }  
  return (await fetch(url, options)).json()
}

async function apiDelete() {
  const url = 'https://apidelete.com/data/v2/all'
  const options = {
    method: 'DELETE',    
  }
  return (await fetch(url, options)).json()
}

async function getItems() {
  const url = 'https://apiget.com/data/v2/all'
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',    
  }  
  return (await fetch(url, options)).json()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a recursive call with an exit condition that asks it to exit when the number of elements is 0.

One way could be something like this:

```
async function deleteUntilEmpty() {
  await apiDelete();
  const items = await getItems();

  if (items.length) {
    return deleteUntilEmpty();
  }
}

async function run() {
  await deleteUntilEmpty();
  apiPost()
    .then(() => console.log("posting..."))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Instead of deleting constantly, you might as well just poll to see if the server has completed the original delete:

```
async function pollUntilEmpty() {
  const items = await getItems();

  if (items.length) {
    // this could be a good spot to introduce some kind of 
    // sleep to not DDOS your server ;)
    return pollUntilEmpty();
  }
}

async function deleteAndPollUntilEmpty() {
  await apiDelete();
  await pollUntilEmpty();
}

async function run() {
  await deleteAndPollUntilEmpty();
  apiPost()
    .then(() => console.log("posting..."))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: `deleteUntilEmpty` should be an `async` function.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, if I recursively call the deleteUntilEmpty() function, it will not invoke the apiDelete() method again?

Comment: Hi, it was a little unclear which definition of `deleteUntilEmpty` you referred to, since I made two versions, one that would apply the delete action repeatedly and one that did not. I updated the answer to make it clearer, calling the second `deleteAndPollUntilEmpty` to make it easier to understand. This will only delete once per call and then just fetch new results until they return an empty list.

Comment: Hi @oligofren, I can see the updated answer now, thank you, buddy, it works